# Postgresql odbc_fdw connection not working

Tags: postgresql, odbc

Am trying to connect postgresql to another databas (MySQL) using ODBC_FDW, Am trying to follow the steps mentioned in the github page as below but after trying the below I keep getting the error

```
ERROR:  Connecting to driver
SQL state: 58000 

CREATE EXTENSION odbc_fdw schema td_tci;
CREATE SERVER mysql_server
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER odbc_fdw
  OPTIONS ( dsn 'mysql');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
  SERVER mysql_server
  OPTIONS (odbc_UID 'root', odbc_PWD 'root');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE td_tci.tsi_lead_queue (
    columns...
)
SERVER mysql_server
  OPTIONS (
        --schema 'tci',
        --table 'tsi_lead_queue',
        sql_query 'select * from tsi_lead_queue'
  );
select * from td_tci.tsi_lead_queue
```

Comment: have you got the odbc driver for mysql installed

Comment: I created an ODBC connection on windows and it's working when I test it, is there something I need to do on postgres side ?

Answer (score 0):

it's working now, I had to define the DSN as system DSN not User's, after doing that it worked fine